# $\frac 1n \sum_{k=c+1}^n X_k X_{k-c}$ converges a.s to $0$ when $X_n$ is i.i.d. with mean $0$.

Tags: probability-theory, independence, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

> Let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d. random variables in $L^2$ with $ E(X_1)=0$. Let $c>0$ be a constant. Then $\frac 1n \sum_{k=c+1}^n X_k X_{k-c}$ converges almost surely to $0$.

I need this statement to prove some result related to time series. This looks very much like some consequence of the Law of Large Numbers, but the $(X_n X_{n-c})$ may not be i.i.d. (if $X_{n}(w)=0$ then $(X_n X_{n-c})(w)= 0$ and $(X_{n+c} X_{n})(w)= 0$, so there is some kind of dependence) , which makes things difficult. I'm quite clueless, so any hint is welcome.

Comment: The case c=0 doesn't look right - The convergence is to the variance.  For c>0, it should work - independence of $X_k$.

Comment: Indeed, you need $c>0$. Then this is true. I know essentially two ways to prove it. 1) Split up $\{k \geq 1\}$ into subsequences $(k_i)$ on which the $X_{k_i} X_{k_i-c}$ are i.i.d. ; use the SLLN, recombine. 2) Use a stronger theorem, e.g. Birkhoff's ergodic theorem, which yields what you want immediately.

Comment: @D.Thomine can you elaborate on the ergodic approach? I'm not very familiar with Birkhoff's theorem. It seems I have to find a measure preserving transformation, but I don't see any.

Answer (score 1):

Write 
$$
\sum_{k=c+1}^n X_k X_{k-c}=\sum_{a=0}^{2q-1}\sum_{i\mid c+1\leqslant 2qi+a\leqslant n}X_{2qi+a}X_{2qi+a-c}
$$
and for any fix $a$, the sequence $\left(X_{2qi+a}X_{2qi+a-c}\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ is i.i.d. and centered.